# why ruby prawn draw from bottom

Tags: ruby, prawn

I am using prawn in ruby and draw a sample text, but why it render from bottom instead of from top?

```
require 'prawn'
require 'prawn/measurement_extensions'

def self.generate
  pdf = Prawn::Document.new(page_size: 'A4', margin: [5.mm, 10.mm, 5.mm, 10.mm])
  pdf.draw_text "Hello world", at: [0, 0]
  pdf.dash 2, space: 3
  pdf.vertical_line 0, 100, :at => 0
  pdf.line_width = 0.5
  pdf.stroke
  pdf.render_file "#{__dir__}/test.pdf"
end
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, as stated in the manual - https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/c504ae4e683017d7afadece084734a9190230cd8/manual/basic_concepts/origin.rb#L5, PDF documents have their origin (0,0) at the bottom left of the page.  Therefore when you specifically tell something to draw at [0,0] it will draw at the bottom left of its encapsualating bounding box, which in your case is the page.